# ajax and php checking username code

Tags: php, ajax

PHP :

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != ""){
    $user= $_POST['username'];
    if(strlen($user<4)){
        echo"username must be 8 charter";
    }
}
```

JS :

```
function callme() {
     var showme = document.getElementById("show");
     var user = document.getElementById("uname").value;
     //for check new browser show ajax from
     if (user !== "") {
         showme.innerHTML = '<h1> loading.....</h1>';
         var hr = new XMLHttpRequest() {
             hr.open("post", "index.php", true);
             hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             hr.readystatechange = function () {
                 if (hr.readystate == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                     showme.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
                 }
             }
             var v = "username=" + user;
             hr.send(v);
         };
     }
}
```

HTML :

```
<span>username:</span>
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"   onkeyup="callme();"/>
<div id="show"></div>
```

My code are not working, and not showing any errors.

The `callme();` function is where I think the error is, which is processing username validation.

Comment: Are you sure your error report is on?

Comment: how to check error please help me i am biginner

Comment: your code is missing one bracket `}` before `</script>` tag.

Comment: if(user!=="") I don't know/can't find this !== operator

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it `E_NOT_WORKING` is not a know PHP error code. You might want to hire a developer.

Answer (score 1):

In Your code you have SyntaxError.

Please add }  after function body.
it's working

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != "")
  {
     $user= $_POST['username'];
    if(strlen($user)<4) /// your mistake in php code
  {
echo"username must be 8 charter";
  }
 }
 ?>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function callme()
 {
var showme = document.getElementById("show");
var user = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    //for check new browser show ajax from
 if(user!=="")
 {
 showme.innerHTML='<h1> loading.....</h1>';
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest()
{
 hr.open("post","index.php",true);
   hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.readystatechange=function()
 {
  if(hr.readystate== 4 && hr.status==200) {
  showme.innerHTML= hr.responseText;
  }
  } 
  var v="username="+ user;
   hr.send(v);  
  }
}// you missed

</script>
  </head>
   <body>
 <span>username:</span>
  <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"   onkeyup="callme();"/>
    <div id="show"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Nice beginner friendly answer! Also I want to point OP at  using F12 / Console to find errors in JS

Comment: php code is not working

Comment: @user3164111 now check i solve your php code mistake.

Comment: @NiravPatel I can't find out what !== does? It doesn't make sense to me, can you explain it?

Comment: my php code not working

Comment: @user3164111 pls check my updated code not your

Comment: duplicate taxtbox show in my page

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != "")
  {
     $user= $_POST['username'];
    if(strlen($user<4))
  {
echo"username must be 8 charter";
  }
 }
 ?>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function callme()
 {
var showme = document.getElementById("show");
var user = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    //for check new browser show ajax from
 if(user!=="")
 {
 showme.innerHTML='<h1> loading.....</h1>';
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest()
{
 hr.open("post","index.php",true);
   hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.readystatechange=function()
 {
  if(hr.readystate== 4 && hr.status==200) {
  showme.innerHTML= hr.responseText;
  }
  } 
  var v="username="+ user;
   hr.send(v);  
  }
}
}// you missed the closing brace.
</script>
  </head>
   <body>
 <span>username:</span>
  <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"   onkeyup=callme() />
    <div id="show"></div>
    </body>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

your final code will be as,

PHP :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != ""){
    $user= $_POST['username'];
    if(strlen($user<4)){
        echo"username must be 8 charter";
    }
}
?>
```

JS :

```
function callme() {
     var showme = document.getElementById("show");
     var user = document.getElementById("uname").value;
     //for check new browser show ajax from
     if (user !== "") {
         showme.innerHTML = '<h1> loading.....</h1>';
         var hr = new XMLHttpRequest() 
         {
             hr.open("post", "index.php", true);
             hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             hr.readystatechange = function () {
                 if (hr.readystate == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                     showme.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
                 }
             }
             var v = "username=" + user;
             hr.send(v);
         };
     }
}
```

you were missing one closing bracket `}` in the `callme()` function.

Comment: my php code not working please help me